# Terminal can't resolve host when trying to install RubyGems on OSX Tiger 10.4.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, rubygems, terminal

I'm about 12 hours new to Ruby on Rails and I'm trying to get all the parts installed on my Mac OSX 10.4.11. I've downloaded Xcode and have followed the install instructions for changing my file path to /usr/local as well as installed Ruby through Terminal as per the Hivelogic Tutorial:

http://hivelogic.com/articles/ruby-rails-mongrel-mysql-osx

I am now copying the recommended code for RubyGems into terminal and I am getting this response:

```
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'files.rubyforge.mmmultiworks.com'
```

What happened?! Does anyone know how I should proceed from here? I was soooo excited to finally get rolling and seeing Ruby Install! I don't want to give up :(

I hope someone can help =)

Comment: Download the sources from here: http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=126 then unpack and run `ruby setup.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

You should checkout [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) for installing all your OS X packages, such as MySQL. I just switched over to it last weekend and can't believe I didn't use it sooner. It takes all the frustration out of installing and upgrading shit and lets you focus on actually building your application.

Comment: I tried Homebrew with no luck. Terminal gives me this message: This script requires the user insertusername to be in the staff group. If this
sucks for you then you can install Homebrew in your home directory or however
you please; please refer to the website. If you still want to use this script
the following command should work:dscl /Local/Default -append /Groups/staff GroupMembership $USER -                            The command mentioned at the end did not work for me. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hmm, it may not be compatible with 10.4. I don't have any way to test with your OS, but it might be worth looking around to see if it's supported. If you can get it working, it's definitely worth the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem using that install tutorial. I've been able to get past that error message by changing "mmmultiworks" to "multiworks." I just figured it was the most likely typo in that command. So that worked.

Except for that the very next command does not work.

```
tar xzvf rubygems-0.9.2.tgz
```

returns...

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
```

Did you figure it out, art_wired? Anyone have any hints?

EDIT:
I figured it out!

Here is how to install rubygems, in the terminal of a mac osx running Tiger.

```
$ curl -O http://files.rubyforge.vm.bytemark.co.uk/rubygems/rubygems-1.2.0.tgz
$ tar xzvf rubygems-1.2.0.tgz
$ cd rubygems-1.2.0
$ cd ..
```

This'll install 1.2.0, which is not hte most up to date version. But updating once you have it is fairly easy. Just

```
$ gem install rubygems-update   
$ update_rubygems
```

Or if you don't want to install an old version first, go to http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=126 and figure out which file you actually want. then put it up in the top line instead of what I have.